# How do I connect my objective-c application with php file?

Tags: php, objective-c

I have made a PHP file that connects to a MySQL server and it works all good but I am unsure on how to connect the Objective-C application that I am working on to the PHP file.

I am wondering how to connect my Objective-C application to the PHP file?

Comment: Use something like the `AFNetworking` library to make calls to your server and retrieve the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out here is the code.

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/write.php];

NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
```